# Controller scope variable not loading until refresh

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a login controller

```
myApp.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        var data = JSON.stringify({user: $scope.user.id, password: $scope.user.password, type: "m.login.password"});
        $http.post("http://localhost:8008/_matrix/client/api/v1/login", data).then(function mySuccess(details){
            $http.post('/login',details.data).success(function(response){
                console.log(response);
            });
            $location.path('home');
        }, function myError(err) {
            console.log(err);
            alert("Invalid username/password")
        });
    };
}]);
```

and a home controller

```
myApp.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    console.log("Hello World from home controller");

    var refresh = function() {
        $http.get('/roomNames').success(function(response) {
            console.log("I got the data I requested");
            $scope.roomNames = response;
        });
    }
    refresh();
}]);
```

As seen, if the login details are correct, the LoginCtrl changes the route to be home.html.

However, when I run the application and login successfully, the HomeCtrl is supposed to make a get request to the server for data for the logged in user.

What I want is this data to be loaded as a list in the home.html. Here's my home.html

```
<h3 class="subHeader"> Rooms </h3>
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <!-- <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li> -->
        <li ng-repeat="room in roomNames"><a>{{room}}</a></li>

      </ul>
```

However, on successful login, the roomNames variable is empty initially. As soon as I refresh the page, the html list gets populated.

How do I ensure the list is populated as soon as the home.html page opens?

Comment: Not sure but Change
     
    $scope.roomNames = response;

to
   
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.roomNames = response;
    })

Comment: try to return $http.get

Comment: When page is loaded first time does this function called?

Comment: This is because, you move on to `home` page before your server you access. Therefore, on the home page, you will not get the data, and get them after the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

try using the success and errorcallbacks from $http, it would be better to place this functionality into a factory

```js
myApp.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location',
  function($scope, $http, $location) {
    console.log("Hello World from home controller");

    var refresh = function() {
      $http.get('/roomNames')
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
          $scope.roomNames = response;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
          //output an error if failed?
        });
    }
    refresh();
  }
]);
```

Comment: This still does not work..I think using a service may be my best bet!

Answer (score 0):

This is because, you move on to home page before your server you access. Therefore, on the home page, you will not get the data, and get them after the refresh.

Do redirected to the page only after successful authentication.

```
myApp.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {
$scope.login = function() {
    var data = JSON.stringify({user: $scope.user.id, password: $scope.user.password, type: "m.login.password"});
    $http.post("http://localhost:8008/_matrix/client/api/v1/login", data).then(function mySuccess(details){
        $http.post('/login',details.data).success(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $location.path('home'); // Redirect after success login
        })
         .catch(function(data){
           console.error("Error in login",data);
         });

    }, function myError(err) {
        console.log(err);
        alert("Invalid username/password")
    });
};
}]);
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Show data in `roomNames` variable.

Comment: When I click on the login button, the path is supposed to change to home.html which does not happen. I am stuck in the login.html page

Comment: It's mean, that your call `$http.post('/login',details.data)` is not success. Add `catch` method.